# Entity Framework Core Query Type not mapping results to object

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to execute a sql query using the new `DBQuery` features in Entity Framework Core 2.1.  I have an entity in my model that looks something like this:

```
public class Ord
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid ColumnOne {get; set;}
    public Guid ColumnTwo {get; set;}
}
```

I have created an object called `TestQuery` which looks like this:

```
public class TestQuery
{
    public Ord PatientOrder {get; set;}
}
```

I have added a new `DBQuery` to my database context class like this:

```
public DbQuery<TestQuery> TestQuery { get; set; }
```

Then, I attempt to execute a query using `FromSql` like so:

```
var query = "select PatientOrder.Id as PatientOrderId,
                    PatientOrder.ColumnOne as PatientOrderColumnOne,
                    PatientOrder.ColumnTwo as PatientOrderColumnTwo
             from Ord PatientOrder"

var test = await _context.TestQuery.FromSql(query).ToListAsync();
```

The list  `test` has the exact number of results that I would expect. However, each `TestQuery` object just has a null `PatientOrder` property. So it appears that the query is running, and returning results, but not mapping the results to the `PatientOrder` property.

Is there a step that I am missing in order to get this data to map to my object correctly?

Comment: I don't know enough to give as an answer, but shouldn't your query aliasing be `PatientOrder.Id as Id, PatientOrder.ColumnOne as ColumnOne`? It can't map because you're aliased names are not the same names as the properties. Plus it seems odd that you're trying to map to an object that contains the actual properties as a subobject. Shouldn't it be at the parent level?

Comment: If I alias PatientOrder.Id as Id, entity framework throws the error `"The required column 'PatientOrderId' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation."` So I know EF is explicilty expecting that naming convention.

Comment: The question is, what's the purpose of `TestQuery`? i.e., why not `DbQuery<Ord>` with `Ord` columns inside SQL?

Comment: @IvanStoev in the question, I was attempting to make the smallest example possible. Im my real life scenario, I have a query that joins to the same table multiple times. So I might have serveral `Ord` objects with different aliases coming back from the same query.

Comment: Ok, so `Ord` is actually an entity. Hmm, interesting, I'm not sure this is supported.

Comment: Try Dapper instead if you're going to be doing raw SQL queries instead of using regular EF.

Comment: @gilliduck Dapper would have the same exact issue.  The issue being you cannot map the class `Ord` to a class `TestQuery`.  Meaning the query is returning a `Ord` class, but you're asking for a `TestQuery`, it makes no sense.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Looks like OP is trying to emulate EF Core regular `Include` query.

Comment: @James Is `Ord` being regular entity a requirement? For instance, can it be owned entity type or query type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do exactly what you are doing [per the documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Excerpt:

> The SQL query cannot contain related data. However, in many cases you can compose on top of the query using the Include operator to return related data (see Including related data).

The following is related data:

```
public Ord PatientOrder {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a query on `TestQuery` which has related data `PatientOrder`, you should use `Include`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#including-related-data

```
var query = "/* do your query, but include the PatientOrderId */";
var test = await _context.TestQuery.FromSql(query).Include(t=>t.PatientOrder).ToListAsync();
```